# What's this strange message that's flooding .xsession-errors?

Tags: 11.04

I have been noticing some instability with my system recently- unexplained freezes, and an occasional inability to suspend: [See bug report here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/957759)

I have been rummaging around the logs, and I see that the following message is flooding my .xsession-errors file.

(nautilus:2076): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

The message seems to be more-or-less continuously generated, not just when I fail to suspend or have another problem.  Any clues what the problem is here?

Thanks in advance!

Charlie

Answer (score 2):

The message is almost certainly unrelated to the freezes. It is a message which is the result of a programming error, either in nautilus itself, or in one of the plug-ins. The message itself doesn't say enough on the console to determine what is the actual cause of it. To figure that out, some more technical debugging is required.